# Nodejs, actualizar datos en mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy tratando de crear un api en donde reciba 2 parametros, el id de la tanda y  y el asiento que se necesita reservar

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "tanda" : "7:30am"
  , "asientos" : [
            0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0 ,0, 0
 ]
},
{
"id":2,
"tanda" : "9:00am",
"asientos" : [
            0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0, 0 ,
   0, 0, 0 ,0, 0
 ]
}
```

el query a mongo es este

```
db.horarios.update({"id":2}, {"$set" : {"asientos.8" : "1"}});
```

pero al querer hacerlo en nodejs

```
router.put('/reservar/:id/:asiento', function(req, res, next) {

horarios.update({"id": req.params.id}, { "$set":{ "asientos." + req.params.asiento +: "1"}}, function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).json({"error"});
  }
  if (doc.result.nModified) {
    res.status(200).json({"status": "ok"});
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({"error": "No se pudo reservar el asiento"});
  }
});
```

me da error de SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Comment: Es obvio; esto no es válido:  "asientos." + req.params.asiento +: "1", deberías hacer: `\`asientos.${req.params.asiento}\`: '1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese error se debe a que a la hora de definir el nombre de una propiedad de un objeto no puedes concatenar cadenas de la forma usual.

Si trabajas con ECMAScript 6 basta con lo siguiente:

```
router.put('/reservar/:id/:asiento', function(req, res, next) {

  horarios.update({"id": req.params.id}, { "$set":{ ["asientos." + req.params.asiento] : "1"}}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      // La línea siguiente también marcaba error porque no asignaste ningún valor a la propiedad error.
      return res.status(400).json({"error" : "Otro error"});
    }
    if (doc.result.nModified) {
      res.status(200).json({"status": "ok"});
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({"error": "No se pudo reservar el asiento"});
    }
  });

}
```

De lo contrario dentro de tu función router.put(), antes de llamar horarios.update(), deberás definir una variable donde guardes la cadena: "asientos." + req.params.asiento. Y luego pasar esta como propiedad en el set.